# Why does my app crash without any errors?

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception

App crashes and I am getting these errors:

---

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                        Process: com.example.ayyan.jellybeanestimator, PID: 2960
>                                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>
> ComponentInfo{com.example.ayyan.jellybeanestimator/com.example.ayyan.jellybeanestimator.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
>                                                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
>                                                                                            at
>   java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1071)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:547)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.example.ayyan.jellybeanestimator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
>                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

```
package com.example.ayyan.jellybeanestimator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;   
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText jellyBeanLength, jellyBeanDiameter, jarSizeVolume;
double jellybeantall, jellybeanfat, jellybeanspace;
double loadFactor = .698;
TextView answer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    jellyBeanLength = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.length);
    jellyBeanDiameter = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.diameter);
    jarSizeVolume = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.jarsize);
    jellybeantall = Double.parseDouble(jellyBeanLength.getText().toString());
    jellybeanfat = Double.parseDouble(jellyBeanDiameter.getText().toString());
    jellybeanspace = Double.parseDouble(jarSizeVolume.getText().toString());
    answer = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.answer);
    Button calculate = (Button) findViewById (R.id.calculate);
    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });



    double volumeOfOneJellyBean =  ((3.14159265359/6)*(jellybeanfat*jellybeanfat)*jellybeantall);
    double volumeofBeans = (jellybeanspace*loadFactor);
    float numberOfBeans = (float)Math.round (volumeofBeans/volumeOfOneJellyBean);
    answer.setText("You have this amount of beans in your jar" + numberOfBeans);
}

}
```

Comment: "App crashes without errors. Getting these errors:" ???

Comment: It has errors.  They just aren't compile time errors.  Not all are.  Your problem is:  Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

Comment: you are converting empty string to double which is not allowed. So firstly check whether its empty or not , than after parse :)

Comment: The crash is caused by `NumberFormatException` and the reason behind it is that one (or more) of your edit text's text is empty.

Before converting your edit text's text to double, check if the texts are empty and also whether they are valid numbers or not.

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class)); Why you call the same activity

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have any value inserted in the `EditText` then only parse it in `Double`

```
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        jellyBeanLength = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.length);
        jellyBeanDiameter = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.diameter);
        jarSizeVolume = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.jarsize);

        answer = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.answer);
        Button calculate = (Button) findViewById (R.id.calculate);
        calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

//Take out value when button pressed
        jellybeantall = Double.parseDouble(TextUtils.isEmpty(jellyBeanLength.getText().toString())?"0":jellyBeanLength.getText().toString());
        jellybeanfat = Double.parseDouble(TextUtils.isEmpty(jellyBeanDiameter.getText().toString())?"0":jellyBeanDiameter.getText().toString());
        jellybeanspace = Double.parseDouble(TextUtils.isEmpty(jarSizeVolume.getText().toString())?"0":jarSizeVolume.getText().toString());



        double volumeOfOneJellyBean =  ((3.14159265359/6)*(jellybeanfat*jellybeanfat)*jellybeantall);
        double volumeofBeans = (jellybeanspace*loadFactor);
        float numberOfBeans = (float)Math.round (volumeofBeans/volumeOfOneJellyBean);
        answer.setText("You have this amount of beans in your jar" + numberOfBeans);
            } 
        }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you should calculate onClick of button.In your code you are not entering any value and trying to calculate it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    jellyBeanLength = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.length);
    jellyBeanDiameter = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.diameter);
    jarSizeVolume = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.jarsize);
    jellybeantall = Double.parseDouble(jellyBeanLength.getText().toString());
    jellybeanfat = Double.parseDouble(jellyBeanDiameter.getText().toString());
    jellybeanspace = Double.parseDouble(jarSizeVolume.getText().toString());
    answer = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.answer);
    Button calculate = (Button) findViewById (R.id.calculate);
    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
    double volumeOfOneJellyBean =  ((3.14159265359/6)*(jellybeanfat*jellybeanfat)*jellybeantall);
    double volumeofBeans = (jellybeanspace*loadFactor);
    float numberOfBeans = (float)Math.round (volumeofBeans/volumeOfOneJellyBean);
    answer.setText("You have this amount of beans in your jar" + numberOfBeans);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no values in the EditText field and you are trying to parse that value.Hence the error java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String.

Answer (score -2):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try
    {
       jellyBeanLength = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.length);
        jellyBeanDiameter = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.diameter);
        jarSizeVolume = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.jarsize);
        jellybeantall = Double.parseDouble(jellyBeanLength.getText().toString());
        jellybeanfat = Double.parseDouble(jellyBeanDiameter.getText().toString());
        jellybeanspace = Double.parseDouble(jarSizeVolume.getText().toString());
        answer = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.answer);
        Button calculate = (Button) findViewById (R.id.calculate);
        calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        double volumeOfOneJellyBean =  ((3.14159265359/6)*(jellybeanfat*jellybeanfat)*jellybeantall);
        double volumeofBeans = (jellybeanspace*loadFactor);
        float numberOfBeans = (float)Math.round (volumeofBeans/volumeOfOneJellyBean);
        answer.setText("You have this amount of beans in your jar" + numberOfBeans);
        }
        });
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more context for your answer. Code by itself isn't an answer

Comment: Try catch isn't solution.

Answer (score -3):

you could try changing:

`answer.setText("You have this amount of beans in your jar" + numberOfBeans);`

to

`answer.setText("You have this amount of beans in your jar" + String.valueOf(numberOfBeans));`

This should convert the double to a string.

Comment: Ay integer value append with strings are consider as final string. So it is not necessary to wrap integer inside string while you are already appending it with string.